# Trying to get weather info from API but the lib HTTPClient.h will not work

Tags: arduino-esp32

```
/* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0bhm-0Z1Sw */
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <credentials.h>

String serverName = "https://api.publicapis.org/entries/";

unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 50000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(__FILE__);
}



void setupwifi() {

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);  //optional
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("\nConnecting");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
  }

  Serial.println("\nConnected to the wiFi network ");
  Serial.print("Local ESP32 IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  callApi();

}  


void callApi() {
  Serial.println("test2");
  Serial.println("test");
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    HTTPClient http;
    String serverPath = serverName;
    http.begin(serverPath.c_str());

    int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
    Serial.print(httpResponseCode);
    Serial.print("httpResponseCode");

    if (httpResponseCode > 0) {}
    Serial.print("HTTP Response Code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    String payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println(payload);
  } else {
    Serial.print(" Error Code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  http.end

 else {
  Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected ");
}

lastTime = millis();
}
void loop() {}
```

I got this errors

```
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2023111-33236-9hag6p.ncf8h\sketch_dec1c\wifiModule.ino: In function 'void callApi()':
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2023111-33236-9hag6p.ncf8h\sketch_dec1c\wifiModule.ino:36:5: error: 'HTTPClient' was not declared in this scope
     HTTPClient http;
     ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2023111-33236-9hag6p.ncf8h\sketch_dec1c\wifiModule.ino:36:5: note: suggested alternative: 'HttpClient'
     HTTPClient http;
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     HttpClient
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2023111-33236-9hag6p.ncf8h\sketch_dec1c\wifiModule.ino:38:5: error: 'http' was not declared in this scope
     http.begin(serverPath.c_str());
     ^~~~
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2023111-33236-9hag6p.ncf8h\sketch_dec1c\wifiModule.ino:51:20: error: 'httpResponseCode' was not declared in this scope
     Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2023111-33236-9hag6p.ncf8h\sketch_dec1c\wifiModule.ino:53:3: error: 'http' was not declared in this scope
   http.end
   ^~~~
Using library WiFi at version 2.0.0 in folder: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.14\libraries\WiFi 
Using library HTTPClient at version 2.0.0 in folder: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.14\libraries\HTTPClient 
Using library credentials in folder: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\credentials (legacy)
exit status 1

Compilation error: 'HTTPClient' was not declared in this scope`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider using code formatting markdown and format error messages to make them more readable. Regarding your question it looks like you have got the `HttpClient` library instead of `HTTPClient` library from Arduino Pico.

Comment: 1) if (httpResponseCode > 0) {} has wrong closing block } at the end; 2) http.end is a method http.end(); and there is a missing termination ; too. 3) there is a missing } right after that for the if block. If you correct all those errors, the code should have work.